# How to insert nodes into list by looping?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list, function-definition

How to Implement in right way to store values into linked list? In this example the last element will be "0" . Is there a possible to write the content of while loop that allows me don't create the last node which will be "0" after allocating in while loop?

```
void store(Stack *a, t_important *data)
{
    int i;
    Stack *tmp;

    tmp = a;
    i = 0;
    while(i < data->length)
    {
        tmp->n = data->collection_of_ints[i];
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        tmp = tmp->next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Input:

> 2->6->0->1->3->5->4

Output:

> 2->6->0->1->3->5->4->0

It is my main function in where i call the store function.

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    Actions action;
    Stack *a;
    Stack *b;
    t_important *data;
    
    if(ac < 2)
        return (-1);
    data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    stack_nums_counter(av, data);
    collect(av, data);
    __check__collection(data);
    __collecting_ints(data);
    action = init();
    a = NULL;
    b = NULL;
    store(&a, data);
    __sort_a__(&a, &b, data, action);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `store` take a `Stack**` instead:

```c
void store(Stack **a, t_important *data) {
    // find last `next`
    while(*a) a = &(*a)->next;

    // insert values
    for(int i = 0; i < data->length; ++i)
    {
        *a = malloc(sizeof **a);
        (*a)->n = data->collection_of_ints[i];
        a = &(*a)->next;
    }
    *a = NULL; // terminate the linked list
}
```

and then call it like so

```c
Stack *my_stack = NULL;
store(&my_stack, &some_t_important_instance);
```

If you instead want to insert the important data *first* in the linked list, you skip the first `while` loop to find the last `next` member:

```
void store(Stack **a, t_important *data) {
    Stack *old_first = *a;
    
    // insert values
    for(int i = 0; i < data->length; ++i)
    {
        *a = malloc(sizeof **a);
        (*a)->n = data->collection_of_ints[i];
        a = &(*a)->next;
    }
    
    // link the last inserted node to the old first node
    *a = old_first;
}
```

Comment: YESSSS. It worked. But now I will to detect the syntax beacuse i don't understand very well what is happening in this code :D. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Davit You're welcome. Please ask if there's anything in particular you want me to explain in more detail.

Comment: I'm just corious to explain this syntax of code. what is meaning this for example: &(*a)->next. And for why we get the last node when before the store function nothing has been inserted in "a" stack?

Comment: `*a` means, dereference `a`, which makes it a `Stack*`. `(*a)->next;` dereferences the pointed out instance's `next` member and `&` takes the address of that `next` member. If `my_stack == NULL` the first while loop will not do anything, since `*a` will be `NULL` in the first iteration. `a` will then still point at `my_stack` after the first `while` loop.

Comment: Great. You described in the very simple way. I'm new in C programming. I still don't know many things. And thank you for every answer!!!

Comment: Great! I added an option how it could look if you want to insert the values _first_ in the list instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247432/discussion-between-davit-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 1):

You always have uninitialized last node of the stack

```
    tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    tmp = tmp->next;
```

So when the stack is outputted then the program invokes undefined behavior.

Also it seems within the caller instead of declaring a pointer of the type `Stack *` you declared an object of the type `Stack` and are passing a pointer to it. It is a bad approach.

Nevertheless using your approach the function can be defined the following way

```
void store(Stack *a, t_important *data)
{
    int i;
    Stack *tmp;

    tmp = a;
    i = 0;
    while(i < data->length)
    {
        if ( i != 0 )
        {
            tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->n = data->collection_of_ints[i];
        tmp->next = NULL;
        i++;
    }
}
```